# How to edit a bounty text?

Tags: feature-request, editing, bounty

[I've just started a bounty](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20468/bounds-on-the-size-of-the-smallest-nfa-for-l-k-distinct) that had a mistake in the text.

I meant we may assume $k=polylog(n)$ while I wrote $k=O(log(n))$.

How can I fix the bounty text?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.